# Using Sql newid() with one more order

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have the following table (namesTbl):

```
 id     name     priority
 -----------------------------------
 1     Steve     2
 2     John      3
 3     Carol     1
 4     Peter     2
 5     Mike      1
```

After running a stored procedure where namesTbl is ordered by newid() then I get, let's say, the following.

```
 id     name     priority
 -----------------------------------
 4     Peter     2
 2     John      3
 5     Mike      1
 1     Steve     2
 3     Carol     1
```

My question is, how can I order the first row ONLY to always be with priority 1? The rest of the rows should be randomly selected. In this case the first row must be either Mike or Carol, since both have priority 1...!!

Thank you

Comment: What does your procedure do? I think you should implement it there.

Comment: You say either Mike or Carol - how do we choose?

Comment: My stored procedure randomize namesTbl (using newid()) and insert the new order in another table

Comment: The first row should always have priority 1 regardless the id and the name. Mike and Carol have both priority 1 and one of them must be randomly in the first row.

Comment: So add to your procedure to take priority one first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select id, name, priority 
  From (SELECT id, name, priority, newPriority
          FROM (select id, name, priority, -1 as newPriority,
                       row_number() over (order by priority) as rn 
                  from namesTBL) tbl
         WHERE rn = 1
         UNION
        SELECT id, name, priority, RAND(100) newPriority 
          FROM (select id, name, priority, 1 as newPriority,
                       row_number() over (order by priority) as rn 
                  from namesTBL) tbl
         WHERE rn > 1
       ) tbl
order by newPriority
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17cbb/3

**EDIT**

There is also a better version:

```
select id, name, priority
  from (select id, name, priority,
               ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100 rnd,
               row_number() over (order by priority) as rn 
          from namesTBL) tbl
order by case when rn=1 then -1 else rnd end
```

See it working on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8cc28/2

Comment: This will work however he wants only 1 row with priority 1 to be first, meaning the rest of priority 1 should be random...